# Relational Database tables for food products - specifying different categories

Tags: database, relational-database, structure, relationship

I am making database design for food products and I am getting lost in deciding how to design product types and categories in database.

Let me share my current database structure:
[image: food product table and its dependencies]

Now lets think of real life example. Lets say if we take **cheese product**. And we just say it is **smoked cheese with some flavor**. Then we can assume that it is dairy product, and it would look something like this: **Dairy -> Cheese -> Smoked -> Garlic flavor**.

I have a list with different food categories and types enclosed:
[image: food categories and types]

I was trying to list just part of it and it becomes very complicated from my point of view.

Two main categories of food would be: **Food** and **Beverages/drinks**, but maybe I should begin with those categories like Bakery, Dairy, Fruit & Vegetables and etc.? Coz then in dairy products I may have food and drinks like **cheese** and **milk**. If we would take only cheese for now, I have googled and there is 66 different types of cheese maybe even more [can be found here](http://holykaw.alltop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/the-charted-cheese-wheel_51ae17314abed.jpg).

I know that everything could be simply added to maybe one table, but as I have so many different categories and types, and they repeats in each other, how could I make an optimal solution for that with the respect to all food categories?

I can conclude that **yes** I am not yet sure how to properly organize all the categories and types, but is there any table structure that you could propose?

If something is not clear enough, please let me know, and I will clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you are looking for some combinations of labeling and categories. A system that could be flexible enough for your case may be implemented as M:N relation of product:label and 1:N of label:label.

This way your cheese example may be labeled like this:

```
Organic type -> Dairy -> Cheese
Cooked -> Smoked
Flavored -> Garlic flavor
```

If your application would allow for fulltext search on labels, adding new products with labels should be easy. End users, on the other hand, will have the possibility to filter through Dairy in general, or Cheese specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The food categories that you have would be better organized in hierarchy. As a relational database you will have overlaps depending on how you organize your products. Ideally, you want to avoid many-to-many at all costs.

Perhaps, it would be better to create relationships based on the purpose of the database. For example, if this is for a supermarket, I would create the relationships based on the vendor and the products they sell, and maybe relate them to the department that receives the products. then add labels, or tags, that categorize the products by what kind of food (dairy, meat, fruits, etc) 
This would allow you to have a more functional system based on process, and adding the tags, would be easily searchable by humans.

So, my suggestion is think about how this would be used and fits into your process and focus on that for the design (schema, relationships). Then focus on the users, and add another layer to make it easy to work with (labels, tags)

Does this make sense?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the database? how will it be used? 
it would be easier to suggest a design with that information